# escape quotes in iMacros block

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to debug a small iMacro code :

```
var go = "CODE:";
go += "VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
go += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
go += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
go += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60" + "\n";
go += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + "\n";
go += "SET !WAITTIME EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
go += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:<SP>fastfollow-user<SP>fastfollow-userUnfollow<SP>js-ff-el&&REL:*" + "\n";
go += "WAIT SECONDS={{!WAITTIME}}" + "\n";

    iimPlay(go);
```

I can't get the syntax right to escape the quotes on the eval, could anyone help me out?

I get : `SyntaxError: illegal character` and variations of that. Tried single quotes, no quotes, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Just use a backslash and a new line:

```
go += "SET !WAITTIME EVAL(\"var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;\")" + "\n";
```